# How to copy a structure(which is a structure within structure) and fill it in the array of structure in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, structure, cen-xfs

I have a structure which a structure within structure as 
shown in this following question :
[How to dynamically fill the structure which is a pointer to pointer of arrays in C++ implementing xfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184208/how-to-dynamically-fill-and-display-the-structure-which-is-a-pointer-to-pointer)

I need to fetch the values of the above structure to another structure that I have created.This structure needs to be considered as array of structure.

```
typedef struct Sp_cashinfo
{
    LPSTR lpPhysicalPositionName;
    ULONG ulInitialCount;
    ULONG ulCount;  
}SP_CASHUNITINFO;
```

This structure is an array of structure since I need to store in a 2D form(i.e 7 times )

```
int CashUnitInfo(SP_CASHUNITINFO *Sp_cdm_cashinfo)
 {
     try
    {
        -----assigned the values----------------
        hResult = WFSGetInfo (hService,dwCategory,lpQueryDetails,dwTimeOut,&lppResult); //assigned the values ,got the response 0 ie success    
        fwCashUnitInfo = (LPWFSCDMCUINFO)lppResult->lpBuffer;               
        USHORT NumPhysicalCUs;
        USHORT count =(USHORT)fwCashUnitInfo->usCount;
        Sp_cdm_cashinfo = (SP_CASHUNITINFO*)malloc(7*sizeof(SP_CASHUNITINFO));      
        for(int i=0;i<(int)count;i++)
        {
    NumPhysicalCUs =fwCashUnitInfo->lppList[i]->usNumPhysicalCUs;
    for(int j=0;j<NumPhysicalCUs;j++)//storing the values of structure
    {
        Sp_cdm_cashinfo[i].lpPhysicalPositionName   =fwCashUnitInfo->lppList[i]->lppPhysical[j]->lpPhysicalPositionName;
        Sp_cdm_cashinfo[i].ulInitialCount           =fwCashUnitInfo->lppList[i]->lppPhysical[j]->ulInitialCount;
    }
    }
 return (int)hResult;
}
```

The above code is been written in a class library needs to be displayed in a class library.

But due to memory allocation problem ,I'm stuck to get garbage value to the structure that I have created.
I have successfully filled the Main Structure( (i.e)Structure within structure) and I require just specific members from this structures

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use a standard container?

Comment: @shuttle87 :what is a standard container??

Comment: Read this: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/containers

Comment: @shuttle87:So u say to use these structure with std::array or std::vector right??? .Yes i do have problem with that because the original structures are pre defined .Hence I created a user defined one

Comment: @shuttle87:I facing problem with memeory due to which it doesnt properly store the data in the created structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this struct:

```
typedef struct Sp_cashinfo
{
    LPSTR lpPhysicalPositionName;
    ULONG ulInitialCount;
    ULONG ulCount;  
}SP_CASHUNITINFO;
```

Assuming that `LPSTR` is from the [windows types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then it is a typedef for `char *` on most modern systems. If that is the case then you need to allocate memory for that array along with the space for the struct. When you create space for this struct you set aside enough memory for storing the pointer and the other 2 data members, however the pointer doesn't yet point to anything that's valid, all you have done is put aside enough space to store the poiner. In the code snippet it looks like the char array here was never actually allocated any memory hence the garbage values.

I would however change this struct to a more idiomatic c++ design like the following:

```
#include <string>
struct Sp_cashinfo
{
    std::string lpPhysicalPositionName;
    uint32_t ulInitialCount;
    uint32_t ulCount;   

    Sp_cashinfo(std::string name, uint32_t initialCount, uint32_t count):
        lpPhysicalPositionName(name),
        ulInitialCount(initialCount),
        ulCount(count)
        {}
};
```

As the memory management with this approach is a lot easier to deal with.
You can then store these structs in a `std::vector` and make a utility function to convert to a raw array *if need be*.

Keeping all your data stored in containers then converting at the boundaries of your code where you call the existing libraries is a better way of managing the complexity of a situation like this.

Comment: @TechBrkTru, just use the constructor.

Comment: Error 2 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int ....I get this error    ,what is another option just declare them as unit???  @shuttle87

Comment: The name for the struct is different if you are going to use the c++ approach but leave the rest of the code mostly unchanged then change  `struct Sp_cashinfo` to `struct SP_CASHUNITINFO`

Comment: I changed `uint32_t` to `unsigned int` and it worked out ,actually no need to change the sttruct name,Another query after setting memory space for this structure ,how should i fill the data??? @shuttle87

Comment: That comes about because you aren't using the newest c++ standard, you can either enable this via a compiler flag to get c++11 support or if you can't do that you might need to use a header file such as `#include <cstdint>` to get those types. As for filling the data, it's the same as before for the most part. If you have all the data at the time of creation of the struct then you can just use the constructor.