# How to allocate memory for an array of structure in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, structure

**Structure 1:**

```
typedef struct _wfs_cdm_cu_info
{
    USHORT usTellerID;
    USHORT usCount;
    LPWFSCDMCASHUNIT * lppList;
} WFSCDMCUINFO, * LPWFSCDMCUINFO;
```

**Structure 2:**

```cpp
typedef struct _wfs_cdm_cashunit
{
    USHORT usNumber;
    USHORT usType;
    LPSTR lpszCashUnitName;
    CHAR cUnitID[5];
    CHAR cCurrencyID[3];
    ULONG ulValues;
    ULONG ulInitialCount;
    ULONG ulCount;
    ULONG ulRejectCount;
    ULONG ulMinimum;
    ULONG ulMaximum;
    BOOL bAppLock;
    USHORT usStatus;
    USHORT usNumPhysicalCUs;
    LPWFSCDMPHCU * lppPhysical;
} WFSCDMCASHUNIT, * LPWFSCDMCASHUNIT;
```

**Structure 3:**

```cpp
typedef struct _wfs_cdm_physicalcu
{
    LPSTR lpPhysicalPositionName;
    CHAR cUnitID[5];
    ULONG ulInitialCount;
    ULONG ulCount;
    ULONG ulRejectCount;
    ULONG ulMaximum;
    USHORT usPStatus;
    BOOL bHardwareSensor;
} WFSCDMPHCU, * LPWFSCDMPHCU;
```

---

**C# structure:-**

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct WFSCDMPHCU {     [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
 public string lpPhysicalPositionName;[System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=5)]
 public string cUnitID;
 public uint ulInitialCount;
 public uint ulCount;
 public uint ulRejectCount;
 public uint ulMaximum;
 public ushort usPStatus;
 public int bHardwareSensor;
}
```

---

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
    public struct WFSCDMCASHUNIT {
     public ushort usNumber;
     public ushort usType;         [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
     public string lpszCashUnitName;[System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=5)]
     public string cUnitID;        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=3)]
     public string cCurrencyID;
     public uint ulValues;
     public uint ulInitialCount;
     public uint ulCount;
     public uint ulRejectCount;
     public uint ulMinimum;
     public uint ulMaximum;
     public int bAppLock;
     public ushort usStatus;
     public ushort usNumPhysicalCUs;
     public System.IntPtr lppPhysical;
    }
```

---

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct WFSCDMCUINFO {    
 public ushort usTellerID;    
 public ushort usCount;      
 public System.IntPtr lppList;
}
```

**DLLImport**

```
[DllImport(@"Dispenser.dll")]
public static extern int CDM_SetCashUnit(out WFSCDMCUINFO cuinfo);
```

1)My main problem is How should I marshall or allocate memory for this structure to send data from C# to C++   ,the second and third structure being array of structure???

2)If I use pointer how efficient it would be.

3)If C++/CLI wrapper be used then how I could access it through C#.

It is been a long time I'm working and I m yet to figure out how should I fill the array of structures in C# .

Follwing code is what i try to figure out...

**Marshal Code:**

Facing an error of "to define an extension non generic static class"

```
 public static IntPtr GetIntPtr(this object obj) {
            try {
                var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                var thread = new Thread(() => {
                    Thread.Sleep(20000);
                    handle.Free();
                });
                thread.Start();

                return handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            } catch (ArgumentException) {
                var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(obj));

                Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, false);

                return ptr;
            }
        }

        public static T FromIntPtr<T>(this IntPtr ptr) {
            if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
                return default(T);

            return (T) Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof (T));
        }
```

A link of C++ code, of how I have called the function is given.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184208/how-to-dynamically-fill-the-structure-which-is-a-pointer-to-pointer-of-arrays-in/30195771?noredirect=1#comment48798363_30195771)

Comment: Then please post the code you wrote when you tried to implement the solution, and describe what happened, so we can help you identify the reason it is not working.

Comment: @phoog : I dont understand how to marshal these structure ,well i get an extension method error when i post the previous link code..I cnt make the class static because it effects the other functions that is been created

Comment: is there any other way to allocate the structure??? @phoog

Comment: The compile error is being caused by having your extension methods in a non-static or generic class.  Either move them to a non-generic static class or make them  regular static methods or, if appropriate, instance methods.

Comment: move which one ???@phoog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79421/discussion-between-phoog-and-techbrktru).

Comment: @TechBrkTru Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is my structure mapping in c#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Message
{
    public uint MsgId;
    public uint DLC;
    public uint Interval;
    public uint Handle;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public byte[] Data;
};
```

C++ here:

```
    struct Message { 
    unsigned int MsgId;
    unsigned int DLC;
    unsigned int Interval;
    unsigned int Handle;
    unsigned char Data[64];
```

} ;

My method in c++ which needs such a structure as a parameter:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int _stdcall MessageWrapper( Message *msg)
```

Here is how i call this method from C#:

```
            Message frame = new Message();
            frame.MsgId = (uint)MsgId;
            frame.DLC = (uint)Dlc;
            frame.Interval = (uint)Interval;
            frame.Data = new byte[64];


            int rawsize = Marshal.SizeOf(frame);
            IntPtr frameBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawsize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(frame, frameBuffer, false);
```

Call the method here:

```
            int response = HwWrapper.MessageWrapper(frameBuffer);
```

You may have some modifications made in c++ and you can read them back here in c#:

```
            frame = (Message)(Marshal.PtrToStructure(frameBuffer, typeof(Message)));


            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(frameBuffer);
```

Comment: Well this is for simple structure ,what about for array of structures??? atleast for third strucutre ....@Olaru Mircea

Comment: Indeed my example doesn't perform that but here is an answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dcfd6310-b03b-4552-b4c7-6c11c115eb45/passing-array-of-struct-with-array-from-c-to-c?forum=clr

Comment: just one of my classes in witch MessageWrapper resides.